# Can NHibernate use internal types?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm a little bit of an NHibernate noobie, and I was wondering if NHibernate can work with internal types.  I have a project with a bunch of internal entities, and I would like to use NHibernate within the project to access my data store.  If I put the mapping files in the same assembly (or is this even necessary?), will NHibernate work with my internal entities?  Or do they need to be declare public?

Answer (score 1):

It can. The mapping files location is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks Diego.  Someone sent this response to me via Twitter -- has this been your experience too?

"NH's own types need to reach into your ass'y and instantiate types so only if you use the [InternalsVisibleTo(..)] attribute"

Comment: No, it hasn't. In my tests, internal classes work fine. But you can always try and see for yourself :-)